# i'm new in work with SQLite in android ,this is my function but that's dosent work

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
public class Rating {

private String _id;
private String _rating;

public Rating(){
}

public Rating(String id, String ration){
    this._id = id;
    this._rating = ration;
 }

public Rating(String ration){
    this._rating= ration;
  }

public String getID(){
    return _id;
}
public void setID(String id){
    this._id = id;
}
 public String getRating(){
    return _rating;
}
public void setRating(String rating){
    this._rating= rating;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return _rating;
 }
 }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
  public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int  DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="ratings.db";

public static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="ratings";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_RATING = "rating";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
        COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        COLUMN_RATING + " text not null);";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
           Log.w(DatabaseHandler.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
    }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
  public class RatingDataSource {

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseHandler dbHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_ID,
        DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_RATING };

public RatingDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public void addRating(Rating rating) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_ID,rating.getID());
    values.put(DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_RATING, rating.getRating());
    database.insert(dbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,null,values);
    db.insert(dbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,null,values);
    db.close();
}
  public Rating getRating(String id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.query(dbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,new String[]{dbHelper.COLUMN_ID,dbHelper.COLUMN_RATING},dbHelper.COLUMN_ID +"=?" ,new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null);
    if (cursor!=null)
     cursor.moveToFirst();
    Rating rating=new Rating((cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1));
    return rating;
}
public void deleteRating(Rating rating) {
   SQLiteDatabase db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    db.delete(dbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,dbHelper.COLUMN_ID+"?",new String[]{String.valueOf(rating.getID())});
    db.close();
}

public List<Rating> getAllRating()
{
    List<Rating> RatingList=new ArrayList<Rating>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHandler.DATABASE_TABLE, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Rating rating = cursorToRating(cursor);
        RatingList.add(rating);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return RatingList;
}
private Rating cursorToRating(Cursor cursor){
    Rating rating = new Rating();
    rating.setID(cursor.getString(0));
    rating.setRating(cursor.getString(1));
    return rating;
  }
 }
```

//////////////this is my error

```
03-04 10:59:47.473: INFO/ActivityManager(277): START u0 {cmp=com.example.sampleebook/.GhasidesingelItem (has extras)} from pid 4030
03-04 10:59:47.483: ERROR/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-04 10:59:47.483: ERROR/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-04 10:59:47.483: ERROR/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-04 10:59:47.483: ERROR/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-04 10:59:47.483: ERROR/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-04 10:59:47.483: ERROR/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-04 10:59:47.483: ERROR/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-04 10:59:47.483: ERROR/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-04 10:59:47.483: ERROR/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-04 10:59:47.483: ERROR/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-04 10:59:47.483: WARN/WindowManager(277): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21020
03-04 10:59:47.934: DEBUG/dalvikvm(4030): GC_CONCURRENT freed 270K, 7% free 5878K/6312K, paused 75ms+27ms, total 192ms
03-04 10:59:48.113: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4030): Shutting down VM
03-04 10:59:48.113: WARN/dalvikvm(4030): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-04 10:59:48.173: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4030): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sampleebook/com.example.sampleebook.GhasidesingelItem}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
        at com.example.sampleebook.RatingDataSource.getRating(RatingDataSource.java:46)
        at com.example.sampleebook.GhasidesingelItem.onCreate(GhasidesingelItem.java:81)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        ... 11 more
03-04 10:59:48.263: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Force finishing activity com.example.sampleebook/.GhasidesingelItem
03-04 10:59:48.273: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Force finishing activity com.example.sampleebook/.Ghasideh
03-04 10:59:48.643: INFO/Choreographer(277): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-04 10:59:48.643: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-04 10:59:48.783: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{410dc930 u0 com.example.sampleebook/.GhasidesingelItem}
03-04 10:59:57.523: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
03-04 10:59:57.523: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{410dc930 u0 com.example.sampleebook/.GhasidesingelItem}
03-04 10:59:58.857: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{40f7c650 u0 com.example.sampleebook/.MyActivity}
03-04 11:00:07.615: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4108c680 u0 com.example.sampleebook/.Ghasideh}
03-04 11:00:07.615: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{410dc930 u0 com.example.sampleebook/.GhasidesingelItem}
03-04 11:00:23.171: DEBUG/ExchangeService(670): Received deviceId from Email app: null
03-04 11:00:23.171: DEBUG/ExchangeService(670): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
03-04 11:00:28.223: DEBUG/ExchangeService(670): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
03-04 11:00:28.233: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-04 11:00:28.233: DEBUG/ExchangeService(670): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
03-04 11:00:28.254: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-04 11:00:28.254: ERROR/ActivityThread(670): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d3ebb8 that was originally bound here
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d3ebb8 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-04 11:00:28.264: ERROR/StrictMode(670): null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d3ebb8 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-04 11:00:28.274: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4109ae40
03-04 11:00:28.274: ERROR/ActivityThread(670): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf11b8 that was originally bound here
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf11b8 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-04 11:00:28.294: ERROR/StrictMode(670): null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf11b8 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-04 11:00:28.294: WARN/ActivityManager(277): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41067308
03-04 11:00:40.103: WARN/ProcessStats(277): Skipping unknown process pid 4067
```

Comment: `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 at `

Comment: whenever you are dealing with curser add this also if( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ){
    num = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ContactNumber")); 
}

cursor.close();

Answer (score 1):

```
if (cursor!=null)
 cursor.moveToFirst();
Rating rating=new Rating((cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1));
return rating;
```

Turn it to:

```
Rating rating = null;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    rating = new Rating((cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1)); 
}
cursor.close();
return rating;
```

Comment: cursor will not be null

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes thank you, you are right. I have corrected my code sample